# Determine what 'sub' element is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `p` element and users can select sections of this text with their mouse. I need to determine what element is selected (in the below example either `p` or `span`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('button').click(function(e) {
  console.log('sel', window.getSelection());
  console.log('h', window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0));

  // How can I determine if a span is selected or a text section of the p?


  // If a span is selected I do nothing except make the span italic
  // If a text section of the p is selected I need to add a span and then make the span italic

  if (window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.nodeType != 'span') {
    var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span = document.createElement("span"); 
    span.appendChild(selectedText); 
    selection.insertNode(span);
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Foo bar <span>span</span></p>

<button>Italicise</button>
```

Comment: The logic doesn't make any sense...wouldn't it be less coding if text within the `<p>` is selected, and then button clicked wraps the text in an `<i>`? If there were preexisting `<span>`s what's the difference between the text in them and text not in a `<span>`?

Comment: @zer00ne If the user selects the text `Foo`; I need to now wrap that text in a `<span>` then make it italic. If the user selects the text `span` I just make it italic. If the user selects `bar span` I would really like to know that both the `p` and `<span>` are selected (and I will then wrap the `bar` text in its own span).

Comment: When you say *"know when the `<span>` is selected"*. Do you mean the user or...?